# Why should the product of the normality of the acid or base and its volume be constant?

Tags: homework, acid-base, titration

$$\ce{N1V1 = N2V2}$$
 where, N is the Normality of the Acid / Base &
 V is the volume in litres. 
We ask you to give a scientific justification or derivation to the above equation
i.e. Why must the product of Normality & Volume be equal for Acid & Base ?

This is a question I found online and would greatly appreciate an answer.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! You may see it helpful if you take a look at common questions about our community, answered in [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help), or taking a little [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. You also may find [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation "How to use LaTex") great for beautifying your future posts.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ce{N1V1 = N2V2}$$ The equation is used basically for dilution of solution and determining one of the parameters of acid or base.

In the case of dilution of solution, the equation holds true because the no of gm equivalents of the solute remains constant in the solution even the solution is diluted.

Initial no of gram equivalents of solute = Final no of gram equivalents of solute ....................eq (1)

And we know, $$\text{Normality} = \frac{\text{No of gram equivalents}}{\text{Volume in Litre}}$$
$$\text{No of gram equivalents}=\text{Normality}\times\text{Volume in Litre}$$
Now lets consider,

Initial Normality =$\ce{N1}$

Initial Volume=$\ce{V1}$

Final Normality=$\ce{N2}$

Final Volume = $\ce{V2}$

Then , eq (1) becomes

$$\text{Initial Normality}\times\text{Initial Volume}=\text{Final Normality}\times\text{Final Volume}$$
$$\ce{N1V1 = N2V2}$$

In case of acid and base reaction,
No of gram equivalents of acid will always react or consume equal no of gram equivalents of base and vice versa

No of gram equivalents of acid = No of gram equivalent of base .......eq (2)

Normality of acid = $\ce{N1}$

Volume of acid =$\ce{V1}$

Normality of base =$\ce{N2}$

Volume of base =$\ce{V2}$

Then eq (2) becomes,
$$\text{Normality of acid}\times\text{Volume of acid}=\text{Normality of base}\times\text{Volume of base}$$

$$\ce{N1V1 = N2V2}$$

The number of grams of a chemical element or compound equal to the weight of its chemical equivalent. The gram equivalent of a chemical element is numerically equal to the quotient resulting from dividing the element’s atomic weight by its valence. For example, the gram equivalent of iron (atomic weight 55.847) with a valence of 2 is 27.92 g and with a valence of 3, 18.62 g. The gram equivalent of acid is that amount of the acid in grams containing one gram equivalent of hydrogen capable of being displaced by metal with the formation of salt. The gram equivalent of a base is that amount of the base in grams that is necessary for its complete reaction with one gram equivalent of acid. The gram equivalent of salt is that amount of the salt in grams containing one gram equivalent of metal. The concept of gram equivalent is widely used in volumetric analysis.

http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Gram+Equivalent

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know when you can use this equation. It is used to find the concentration of the solution when the volume of solvent is changed (when diluting the solute). Since the only thing that changed is the volume of the solvent (the amount of the solute is the same before and after), you use the equation to find the new concentration.

E.g. 100 mL of a 0.2 N solution of sodium chloride is diluted to 0.1 N. The new volume is:
$$\ce {N_{f} \times V_{f} = N_{i} \times V_{i}}$$
$$0.1\ce {N\times V_{f} = } 0.2\ce {N \times 100mL}$$
$$\ce {V_{f} = 200mL}$$